# Show remote file progress with Chef

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

We have a vagrant box that downloads a large file to install. We're using chef recipes to do our provisioning. It takes about an hour to download these files. Is there a way to have chef output the progress of the file download instead of just idling after the remote_file request? I'm looking for something similar to the command line output you see if you just run wget on linux.

The [remote_file docs](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_remote_file.html) don't seem to indicate that this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, that is not possible using the `remote_file` resource. You could [open a issue on the Chef project](https://github.com/opscode/chef) to request this feature.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this in May, 2020 or later. This feature has been added to https://docs.chef.io/resources/remote_file/ and can be used in the form of

show_progress              true, false # default value: false

Example:

```
remote_file installer do
  show_progress true
```

Example output:

```
 - Progress: 0%
 - Progress: 10%
 - Progress: 20%
```